# Tomcat 7 BASH CP copies filename but not the file content?

Tags: bash, tomcat, cp

I have a peculiar issue:

The following BASH script worked fine under Tomcat 5.
When the Tomcat 5 was upgraded to Tomcat 7, the script fails.
(It may be a coincident, I don't know)
The script is started by a response.sendRedirect() statement in a servlet.

The BASH script executes the CP command twice (count = 0, 1).
First time (count = 0) the CP command is executed as expected.
Second time it copies only the filename but not the content of the file.

```
count=0;
while [[ $count -lt ${#param[*]} ]]; do
  echo "cp $dirfrom${param[$count]} $dirto${param[$count]}<br>"
  case ${param[$count]} in
    *.jpg) cp $dirfrom${param[$count]} $dirto${param[$count]} ;;
    *.gif) cp $dirfrom${param[$count]} $dirto${param[$count]} ;;
  esac
  let count++
done
```

As you see, I have a test output line at line 3. If I executes the echoed CP in line 3 manually, the CP executes as expected.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you have any way to make sure that the servlet waits for the operation (Process) to complete? Can you use `rsync` instead of `cp` in the script?

Comment: Same result using rsync and cp. I have also echoed '$?' after each execution which is 0 (zero) in both cases. I have also tried a 'sleep 5' in the while loop just after the 'esac' line to ensure the operation to complete - same result.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks to h3nr1x! Your clue regarding 'operating complete' and testing with rsync made me understand what happened.

Comment: Using rsync with result 0 showed that the file was copied correct i.e. that the file size was actually zero at the time of copy. Therefore I investigated my servlet. This showed that I did not flush/close my file handling before calling the bash script. Adding flush and close, the files are now copied as expected. (Just odd that it worked under Tomcat 5). Anyway thanks!!!